# Insert spacing in long rmarkdown column

Tags: css, r-markdown, blogdown

As part of a post using blogdown I am displaying a list of names in three columns. I'd like to add a space between every group of five names in the RMarkdown document.

I tried `<br>` every five names but that only worked for the first column nor is it very elegant. What is the best way to do this?

[image]

```
<style>
 .col3 {
    columns: 3 100px;
    -webkit-columns: 3 100px;
    -moz-columns: 3 100px;
  }
</style>


<font size = 3>
<div class = "col3">
- Amur Cork
- Apple
- Ash
- Austrian Pine
- Black Cherry
<br>  
- Black Maple
- Black Oak
- Black Willow
- Bur Oak
- Callery Pear 'Chanticleer'
<br>  
- Carolina Poplar
- Colorado Blue Spruce
- Columnar Norway Maple
- Crab Apple
- Eastern Hemlock
<br>  
- European Beech
- Ginkgo
- Hack-Berry
- Honey Locust
- Kentucky-Coffee Tree
<br>
- Linden
- Manitoba Maple
- Maple
- Mulberry
- Norway Maple
<br>
- Oak
- Red (Green) Ash
- Red Maple
- Red Oak
- Sassafras
<br>
- Scotch Elm
- Scots Pine
- Service-Berry
- Siberian Elm
- Silver Maple
<br>
- Silver Queen Silver Maple
- Silver White Poplar
- Skyline Honey Locust
- Sugar Maple
- Tulip-Tree
<br>
- Walnut
- Weeping Willow
- White Ash
- White Oak
- White Pine
<br>
- Willow
- Yew 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first three `<br>` tags have two trailing spaces, after rendering, they appear as

```
  <li>Black Cherry <br><br>
  </li>
```

Without trailing spaces:

```
  <li>Sassafras <br></li>
```

You can add two spaces to the rest `<br>` tags, or you can delete all the `<br>` tags and separate your list with a new line.

Comment: The <br> with two trailing spaces worked better than the new line as the new line left a bullet with no name. However, the number of items in a column before starting a new column seems arbitrary.  Is there a way to force the beginning of a new column?

Comment: @ixodid the css multiple column layout does not have delicate control as you required, please read [this w3c page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-fill.asp) to see more details.

Comment: @ixodid you can still set each column separately and join them together using html/css syntax, but that seems to be an overkill.